# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser on a local server

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

What may be causing "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" to not work on a local server. Can it be a configuration issue?

PHP Version 7.2.12

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
$html->load($html);

?>
```

Gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function load() on
>   string in ..... Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ..... on line .....

Comment: try `file_get_html` instead of `file_get_contents`

Comment: You trying to call `load` method of `$html` that is string

Answer (score 1):

Reading a [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) (which is always an option) says that `load` function is called on instance of `simple html dom`

```
// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a string
$html->load('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');
```

So, your code should be rewritten as:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load(file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/'));
```

As a sidenote - there're **more** methods to load content to `simple_html_dom`, such as `file_get_html` as `str_get_html`.